# Best backend wallet for web service

Tags: client, website-integration

The website I am working on needs to have a web wallet integrated. What is the best solution for for a back end web wallet?

I need something that the web site can interface with to be able to generate an address and sign and send transactions. Looking around I have found BitcoinJS which looks good but I will have to code the wallet myself. I am looking for an existing solution that can be used by my site.

Bitcoind does not scale well in my experience as the wallet gets bloated and starts hogging all the CPU hence a reference implementation is needed.

Comment: Anything without using bitcoind sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. And yes I understand it's not trivial to run. But you should probably want bitcoind with the wallet and private keys on a separate dedicated and hardened system anyway.

Comment: See also this answer: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/40987/5292

Comment: How about a solution that has bitcoind at the very back but uses JS to get the user to do a lot of the heavy loading. I'm thinking of CoinPunk which is now discontinued, it used an early buggy version of BitcoinJS to sign TXs and the Insight API to send transactions through. The API itself used Bitcoin which provided an interface for the Bitcoin network.

If you have a site with tens of thousands of users which interfaces with bitcoind directly for those users then the server is going to die. Better to have some JS so the user can do the heavy lifting.

I'll go do my own research on this one.

Comment: Maybe look into something like this: https://blog.bitpay.com/bitcore-v1/ (I don't have experience with it.)